# Trying to go through an javascript array in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a bot system that requires going through an array of users to contact them for an upcoming event, and having an issue trying to recurse through each array in this object.

The array is

```
var users=bot.servers[bot.serverFromChannel(data['channelid'])].members;
console.log("wee"+util.inspect(users, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
bot.sendMessage({
    to: data['channelid'],
    message: "Hello World",
}, function(response) { 
    console.log("Alright"+users.length)
    for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
        bot.editMessage({
            channel: data['channelid'],
            messageID: response.id,
            message: "Hello <@"+users[i].user.id+">"
        });
        console.log("wee"+util.inspect(users[i], {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
    };
    /*bot.deleteMessage({
        channel: data['channelid'],
        messageID: response.id
    });*/
});
```

So far it goes through, posting the array table and posting 'Hello World', but stops at Alright with undefined.

The array table is like this

```
{
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {},
    "_eventsCount": 6,
    "connected": true,
    "servers": {
        "923946464": {
            "voice_states": [],
            "roles": {
                "92394097364": {
                    "position": -1,
                    "permissions": 369089,
                    "name": "@everyone",
                    "managed": false,
                    "id": "92394464",
                    "hoist": false,
                    "color": 0
                }
            },
            "region": "us-east",
            "presences": [
            ],
            "owner_id": "9236892256",
            "name": "Group",
            "members": {
                "92368969305952256": {
                    "user": {
                        "username": "Nickoplier",
                        "id": "9256",
                        "discriminator": "6",
                        "avatar": "b37f9a293e509"
                    },
                    "roles": [],
                    "mute": false,
                    "joined_at": "2000-01-01T01:01:09.497000+00:00",
                    "deaf": false,
                    "status": "online",
                    "game_id": null
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your "wee" line shows the variable `users` with the correct data?

Comment: "wee" doesn't even run due to users.length being undefined.

Comment: Check that the value of `data['channelid']` is actually "923946464" because I suspect that users is `undefined` because you're getting `.members` on an object without that property.

Comment: Oh, should've asked which "wee" you were referring to. The first "wee" does post in the console all the users in that channel. The second "wee" doesn't post into the console.

Comment: OH, I see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`members` is an object, not an array. Use `Object.keys` to get an array of the keys.

```
Object.keys(users).forEach(function(key) {
   var user = users[key];
   // Do stuff to user
});
```

If you're in an environment that doesn't support `Object.keys`, add [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) or use the following:

```
for (var key in users) {
  if (users.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var user = users[key];
    // Do stuff to user
  }
}
```